# Extract words from random strings

Tags: python, string, list, text-extraction

Below I have some strings in a list:

```
some_list = ['a','l','p','p','l','l','i','i','r',i','r','a','a']
```

Now I want to take the word `april` from this list. There are only two `april` in this list. So I want to take that two `april` from this list and append them to another `extract` list.

So the extract list should look something like this:

```
extract = ['aprilapril']
```

or

```
extract = ['a','p','r','i','l','a','p','r','i','l']
```

I tried many times trying to get the everything in `extract` in order, but I still can't seems to get it.

But I know I can just do this

```
a_count = some_list.count('a')
p_count = some_list.count('p')
r_count = some_list.count('r')
i_count = some_list.count('i')
l_count = some_list.count('l')

total_count = [a_count,p_count,r_count,i_count,l_count]
smallest_count = min(total_count)

extract = ['april' * smallest_count]
```

Which I wouldn't be here If I just use the code above.

Because I made some rules for solving this problem

---

Each of the characters (a,p,r,i and l) are some magical code elements, these code elements can't be created out of thin air; they are some unique code elements, that has some uniquw identifier, like a secrete number that is associated with them. So you don't know how to create this magical code elements, the only way to get the code elements is to extract them to a list.

Each of the characters (a,p,r,i and l) must be in order. Imagine they are some kind of chains, they will only work if they are together. Meaning that we got to put `p` next to and in front of `a`, and `l` must come last.

These important code elements are some kind of top secrete stuff, so if you want to get it, the only way is to extract them to a list.

---

Below are some examples of a **incorrect** way to do this: (breaking the rules)

```
import re

word = 'april'
some_list = ['aaaaaaappppppprrrrrriiiiiilll']

regex = "".join(f"({c}+)" for c in word)
match = re.match(regex, text)

if match:
    lowest_amount = min(len(g) for g in match.groups())
    print(word * lowest_amount)
else:
    print("no match")
```

```
from collections import Counter

def count_recurrence(kernel, string):
     # we need to count both strings
     kernel_counter = Counter(kernel)
     string_counter = Counter(string)

    effective_counter = {
        k: int(string_counter.get(k, 0)/v)
        for k, v in kernel_counter.items()
    }

    min_recurring_count = min(effective_counter.values())

    return kernel * min_recurring_count
```

This might sounds really stupid, but this is actually a hard problem (well for me). I originally designed this problem for myself to practice python, but it turns out to be way harder than I thought. I just want to see how other people solve this problem.

If anyone out there know how to solve this ridiculous problem, please help me out, I am just a fourteen-year-old trying to do python. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you can just use the `in` operator instead of `regex` to extract words that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "cannot copy nor delete the magical codes" - if you want to put them in your output list you will need to "copy" them somehow.

And btw your example code (`a_count = some_list.count('a')` etc) won't work since `count` will always return zero.

That said, a possible solution is

```
worklist = [c for c in some_list[0]]
extract = []
fail = False
while not fail:
    lastpos = -1
    tempextract = []
    for magic in magics:
        if magic in worklist:
            pos = worklist.index(magic, lastpos+1)
            tempextract.append(worklist.pop(pos))
            lastpos = pos-1
        else:
            fail = True
            break
    else:
        extract.append(tempextract)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to `pop` the elements when you find them, you may compute the positions of all the occurences of the first element (the "a"), and set `lastpos` to each of those positions at the beginning of each iteration

Comment: Yeah, my idea is a bit too abstract, the rules aren't that clear. I will delete the rule of "can't copy nor delete", I am now sure what I even meant myself at the first place, thanks for taking notice!

Comment: You seem to have changed your question. The example was a list containing just one long string, while now it contains many one char strings. But apart from that in the first version it seemed you wanted to find the letters in "april" only in that order: under that requirement there are no occurrences of "april" in the current input list since there are no "l"s following an "i". My solution won't work with this new version of the question :(

Comment: It's ok, I just thought of that I would be easier for people to solve this problem if the strings were like that. The long string one is actually the original string that I have in my code, the one that I just change to is the one that I got stuck on. But you actually solve the whole thing, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most efficient way, although code works and is more explicit to understand the program logic:

```
some_list = ['aaaaaaappppppprrrrrriiiiiilll']
word = 'april'
extract = []
remove = []
string = some_list[0]

for x in range(len(some_list[0])//len(word)): #maximum number of times `word` can appear in `some_list[0]`
  pointer = i = 0
  while i<len(word):
    j=0
    while j<(len(string)-pointer):
      if string[pointer:][j] == word[i]:
        extract.append(word[i])
        remove.append(pointer+j)
        i+=1
        pointer = j+1
        break
      j+=1
    if i==len(word):
      for r_i,r in enumerate(remove):
        string = string[:r-r_i] + string[r-r_i+1:]
      remove = []
    elif j==(len(string)-pointer):
      break
print(extract,string)
```